# WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, devise

Info:
I'm on development. Running on port 3000 on http.
On my sign in page, the only session info is =

```
:_csrf_token    "JISqEbDHAxteJM2E96/S/9iimgBLwVsLP37CpvIBo/A="
```

Sign in form has this hidden element:

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="JISqEbDHAxteJM2E96/S/9iimgBLwVsLP37CpvIBo/A=">
```

So the CSRF seems to match. But when I enter my user name and password, first it says **WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity** then in the logs I see that it updates my 'last_sign_in', which leads me to believe it successfully logs in. `devise::sessionsController#create` is being called.

### Things I've confirmed:

1. `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` has `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in it
2. `jquery_ujs.js` is being loaded on the page, which I believe adds CSRF info to any jquery ajax requests.

I started messing with my application server around the time this problem came up.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the root cause, but just a higher level reason was the fact that I was not serving it with SSL certs. This, somehow, was causing it not to work. Once I added SSL instead of HTTP to my development app, it all worked again. Anyone have an idea why?